# Set text to dd element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to set text to dd element. I've tried to google that question, but found nothing.

Could you please tell me, how can I set(replace) text inside dd tag?

I've tried:

```
$('#dd_di').innerHTML = my_var; 
$('#dd_di').innerText = my_var; 
$('#dd_di').innerText = "3500";
```

but nothing changed.

```
console.log($('#dd_di')); 

[<dd id="dd_di"></dd>]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use DOM properties on a jQuery object. In jQuery, use `.text()` or `.html()` to set the text and raw HTML of an element respectively.

```
$('#dd_di').text(my_var);
$('#dd_di').html(my_var); // or if you need to set the raw HTML
```

`innerHTML` and `innerText` can be used, but you need to access the DOM element:

```
$('#dd_di').get(0).innerHTML = my_var;

// or no jQuery:
document.getElementById("dd_di").innerHTML = my_var;
```

Answer (score 2):

use [$('#element_id').html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/), do:

```
$('#dd_di').html("your text");
```

demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sA4K/)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
$('#dd_di').text("custom text"); 
});

<dd id="dd_di">hello</dd>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5RPaZ/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DOM properties on the DOM objects:

```
window.dd_di.innerHTML = my_var;
window.dd_di.innerText = my_var;
```

DOM elemnets with are available in the global (`window`) objects. You can also be more explicit:

```
document.getElementById('dd_di').innerHTML = my_var;
document.getElementById('dd_di').innerText = my_var;
```

Both work without jQuery. Normally you'd consistently use either jQuery (see other answers) or native DOM api.